# Space is needed in generated bounty notice

Tags: bug, bounties

In the bounty notice there isn't any space between the end of one sentence and the beginning of the next. E.g.,

> [image: Bounty notice]

Link to the [list of MSE bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) for check by self.

Comment: Missing space isn't related to spelling.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars whydoyouthinkso?